# Profile preferences doesn't apply in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code. I try to download file using selenium so I want to disable pop up save window but all I've tried didn't work for me. Save window keep showing up. I use Mozilla Firefox and Windows 10.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "./")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "attachment/csv")
binary = '/Users/User/Documents/Geckodriver/geckodriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = binary, firefox_profile = profile)
```

If it is important I use Firefox as my regular browser maybe it can somehow affect geckodriver.

I add update line before binary line and it didn't help me.

```
profile.update_preferences()
```

I found all these preferences in about:config and they all actually have been applied:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebFND.png)

Actually I try to download mp3 file if this matters

Answer (score 0):

Once you set all the preferences through `profile.set_preference()` lines, finally you need to update the preferences using the line:

```
profile.update_preferences()
```

So effectively, your code block will be:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "attachment/csv")
profile.update_preferences()
binary = '/Users/User/Documents/Geckodriver/geckodriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = binary, firefox_profile = profile)
```

Comment: So, I've done this and it still pops up. I wrote update line right before binary line